# Select DB name where record does not exist in table 'X'

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I would like to query the server for all database names that do not have 3 records with specific ID's. Not all databases on the server will have the same structure, but most will.

I need the names to know which databases to run the update scripts on.

Thank you.

**EDIT**

There should be 3 records in table `ACTIONS` with "ID" equal to 9, 10 and 11. If all 3 do not exist, I need the name to run an update script on.

I tried using `sys.databases` and `sys.tables` but I am unsure how to join the tables and check for the three records.

Comment: Can you show us the table or database layout, and what you have tried?  This shouldnt be too hard, question is a little vague.

Comment: The column is called `ID` in every `ACTIONS` table? Or is it the first column in every table you need to look in?

Comment: It is always the column ID of the ACTIONS table. Not all databases will have the table ACTIONS though.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need dynamic SQL for this.

The following script will find the tables without those `ID` values, in all *online* user databases that have a table called `ACTIONS`, and perform the insert for any `ID` values that don't already exist.

(I'm making an assumption here that it is in the `dbo` schema, and that no table called `ACTIONS` will exist in any schema other than `dbo`.)

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql += N'
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ' + QUOTENAME(name) 
  + '.sys.tables WHERE name = N''ACTIONS'') 
EXEC sp_executesql N''IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ' + QUOTENAME(name) 
  + '.dbo.ACTIONS WHERE ID = 9) INSERT ' + QUOTENAME(name) 
  + '.dbo.ACTIONS(ID /* ..., other cols ... */)
   SELECT 9 /* ..., other cols ... */;'';
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ' + QUOTENAME(name) 
  + '.sys.tables WHERE name = N''ACTIONS'') 
EXEC sp_executesql N''IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ' + QUOTENAME(name) 
  + '.dbo.ACTIONS WHERE ID = 10) INSERT ' + QUOTENAME(name) 
  + '.dbo.ACTIONS(ID /* ..., other cols ... */)
   SELECT 10 /* ..., other cols ... */;'';
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ' + QUOTENAME(name) 
  + '.sys.tables WHERE name = N''ACTIONS'') 
EXEC sp_executesql N''IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ' + QUOTENAME(name) 
  + '.dbo.ACTIONS WHERE ID = 11) INSERT ' + QUOTENAME(name) 
  + '.dbo.ACTIONS(ID /* ..., other cols ... */)
   SELECT 11 /* ..., other cols ... */;'';'
FROM sys.databases WHERE state = 0 AND database_id > 4;

PRINT @sql
-- EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

This just prints the command, and it will only print 8K due to limitations in Management Studio, so don't be alarmed if you have a lot of databases and the command appears truncated. When you are happy it is going to do what you want, comment the `PRINT` and uncomment the final `EXEC`.

You'll have to fill in the other parts (e.g. I imagine `ID` is not the only column - so replace `/* ..., other cols ... */` with whatever constant values you want for `ID = 9, 10, 11`. Note that you'll need double-double-delimiters on any string literals, so one of the commands may end up looking like this:

```
+ '.dbo.ACTIONS WHERE ID = 9) INSERT ' + QUOTENAME(name) 
+ '.dbo.ACTIONS(ID, Description)
 SELECT 9, ''''The description'''';'';
```

Comment: I just need the name of the database and I don't want to insert the record. I modified it to just print the DB name. This helped a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Aaron Bertrand for your help. I had to modify the SQL to only select the DB names and to find databases with a certain preifx.

```
SELECT @sql += N'
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ' + QUOTENAME(name) + '.sys.tables WHERE name = N''Action'') 
  BEGIN
      EXEC sp_executesql N''IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ' + QUOTENAME(name) + '.dbo.Action     WHERE Id = 9 OR ID = 10 OR ID = 11) 
      PRINT ''''' + QUOTENAME(name) + ''''' ''
   END'
   FROM sys.databases WHERE state = 0 AND database_id > 4 and name LIKE 'AAA%';

--PRINT @sql
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```